# как в angular вывести информацию, полученную через get?

Tags: javascript, http, angular2, promise

как мне в `tmp` записать полученные данные? Через `return` из функции возвращается объект `promise`, а в самой функции `tmp` не видно

```
tmp: string;

constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.tmp = "load";
  this.GetUsers();
}

ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(console.log("Hello"), 2000);
}
GetUsers() {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/users')
    .toPromise()
     .then(function(response) {
       this.tmp = "success"
     })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

плюс этому не работает `setTimeout`. То есть он срабатывает лишь раз и все.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить функцию на стрелочную. .then((response) => {
       this.tmp = "success"
     })

Comment: @НазарКалитюк получилось!) но вопрос с выводом из функции все равно открыт. С промизами я плохо дружу

Comment: Попробуйте async await. По промисам можете посмотреть видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNEDPtVchfw&t=2s или на этом же канале есть курс по ангуляр 2

Comment: Для чего вам список юзеров? Ангуляр умеет выводить результаты асинхронных запросов в темплейт с помощаю пайпа `async`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Получать любые данные надо в ngOnInit
2. Если версия ангуляра 4.3+ то юзай HttpClient

   ```
   public tmp: string;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { // не забудь заимпортить этот модуль

   }

   ngOnInit() {
     setTimeout(console.log("Hello"), 2000);
     this.GetUsers()
        .do(() => this.tmp = 'load')
        .subscribe(data => {
           this.tmp = data;
         });
   }

   private getUsers(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:1337/api/users')
   }
   ```